# How do I get the first name on a list arraylist

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, arraylist

```
public String firstName(ArrayList<String> nameList)
{

   String name="";
   for(int i=0; i<nameList.size();i++) {
      name=nameList.get(i);
   }
   return name;
}
```

I have an input list of names:

- Jerry, Mike, Sandy, Todd
- Todd, Mike, Jerry, Sandy
- Sandy, Jerry, Todd, Mike
- Mike, Jerry, Todd, Mike

Using the `arraylist`, I want to get the **firstname** of each line. So in this case, `Jerry, Todd, Sandy, Mike.`

Here's how it is set up in the **class** and how I originally had it

How do I **return** just the first name to each line?

Comment: Language?? Even knowing that it wouldn't be yet understandable.

Comment: How are the lines separated? Would you have a "\n" in the `nameList`?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's java. In the main class, I use a scanner to input the files. The files are read with four names per line.

Answer (score 0):

do some thing like this at the end

```
return firstName = (name.indexOf(" ")>-1)?name.subStr(0,name.indexOf(" ")+1):name;
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do it? I don't understand that line of code. I do not know iterator either.

Comment: the line is equivalent to:


if(name.indexOf(" ")>-1){
 return name.subStr(0,name.indexOf(" ")+1);
}
else {
 return name;
}